# javascript - Detect if Google Analytics is loaded yet?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm working on a project here that will store some info in Google Analytics custom variables. The script I'm building out needs to detect if GA has loaded yet before I can push data to it. The project is being designed to work across any kind of site that uses GA. The problem is reliably detecting if GA has finished loading or not and is available.

A couple of variabilities here:

1. There's multiple methods of loading GA. Older scripts from the Urchin days up to the latest asynchronous scripts. Some of these are inline, some are asynchronous. Also, some sites do custom methods of loading GA, like at my job. We use YUI getScript to load it.
2. Variable-variable names. In some scripts, the variable name assigned to GA is `pageTracker`. In others, its `_gaq`. Then there's the infinity of custom variable names that sites could be using for their implementation of GA.

So does anyone have any thoughts on what might be a reliable way to check if Google Analytics is being used on the page, and if it's been loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Google Analytics or Universal Analytics is installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510183/check-if-google-analytics-or-universal-analytics-is-installed)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function checkIfAnalyticsLoaded() {
  if (window._gaq && window._gaq._getTracker) {
    // Do tracking with new-style analytics
  } else if (window.urchinTracker) {
    // Do tracking with old-style analytics
  } else {
    // Retry. Probably want to cap the total number of times you call this.
    setTimeout(checkIfAnalyticsLoaded, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: "Then there's the infinity of custom variable names that sites could be using for their implementation of GA." Checking for individual variable names isn't going to work universally.

Comment: Only if you need to actually interact with the custom variable names that sites have made up. Just checking for the old and new versions of analytics will tell you if it is "being used on the page and loaded".

Comment: Instead of checking for `window.pageTracker`, it's best to just check for the existence of the actual function: `if ( _gat && _gat._getTracker ) { /* new style analytics */ }`

Comment: This fails on browsers with Ghostery installed as it mocks tracking code with surrogates for compatibility on sites. To overcome this you should additionally do _gaq(['_link', yourURL]) if you track hits on external assets (like PDFs). It tracks a hit for normal ga.js and sets window.location.href = yourURL in Ghostery's surrogate.

Comment: The setTimeout syntax isn't correct : ```setTimeout(checkIfAnalyticsLoaded, 500);```

Answer (score 40):

This, you can put the code **above/before** the **Google Analytics Tracking Code** :

```
function check_ga() {
  if (typeof ga === 'function') {
    console.log('Loaded :'+ ga);
  } else {
    console.log('Not loaded');
    setTimeout(check_ga,500);
  }
}
check_ga();
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/rijiyojume/edit?html,console

---

Or If you can run script **after** the **Google Analytics Tracking Code** :

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  console.log(tracker.get('clientId'));
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/wiqategifo/1/edit?html,console

**Ref:** [#ready-callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#ready-callback)

Comment: `ga` doesn't constitute if google analytics is loaded. You can verify this by checking if `ga.q.length` ever decreases.

Comment: This only works for Universal Analytics implementations.  It does not support legacy implementations.

Comment: @l2aelba this will run forever if browser block google analytics

Answer (score 25):

I'm too lowly to respond to Annie's answer which works but has syntax errors. Analytics names have underscore first and the setTimeout() syntax was backwards (and incomplete). It should be this:

```
function checkIfAnalyticsLoaded() {
  if (window._gat && window._gat._getTracker) {
    // Do tracking with new-style analytics
  } else if (window.urchinTracker) {
    // Do tracking with old-style analytics
  } else {
    // Probably want to cap the total number of times you call this.
    setTimeout(checkIfAnalyticsLoaded, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I have to do : setTimeOut(checkIfAnalyticsLoaded, 500);

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I did it:

```
var ga = window[window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] || 'ga'];
if (typeof ga == 'function') {
  // call ga object here
  ga('send', 'event', 'Social Share Button', 'click', 'facebook');
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful because it accounts for implementations where the global object exposed by Google's API has been renamed.  This is configurable from within Google Tag Manager.  @see: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2574372?hl=en#TrackerName

Comment: Correction: tracker name is customizable from within GTM.  The global function name is customizable within the JS tag itself.

Comment: I took your code, wrapped in a function and put that function in the Google Analytics JS file. Can confirm it works without a hitch, at least for me.

Answer (score 8):

### ECMA2015 style

```
let checkIfAnalyticsLoaded = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let timeStart = Date.now();
    const TIMEOUT = 3000;

  let _isLoaded = function() {
    if (Date.now() - timeStart > TIMEOUT) {
      reject('Timeout. Google analytics not injected!');
      return;
    }
    if (window.ga && ga.create) {
      resolve(ga);
      return;
    } else {
      setTimeout(_isLoaded, 500);
    }
  };

  _isLoaded();
  });
}


checkIfAnalyticsLoaded()
  .then((result => {
    console.log('LOADED', result);
  }))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 8):

None of the above methods worked well for me. Maybe because I am loading GA through GTM, not sure. But this simple method did work from the console for me :

```
ga.loaded
```

If you are trying to check from within your script, you may need to wait a bit as GA is loaded after doc ready :

```
var t = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(ga.loaded);
}, 999);
```

Comment: This was the method that worked for me, because the newer GA script snippets *always* have a `ga()` function, which is created locally if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This is the only method that works, others methods is outdated

Answer (score 5):

Simply check this object after window load event.

```
if(window.google_tag_manager){ /*It's loaded!*/ }
```

Comment: This works for me in 2023 using GA4, all other answers made for the old version of Analytics aren't working anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Adjusted version to wait for Google Analytics to not only have finished loading, but als have generated the clientId (in case you need it, like I do). Also added a cap on amount of retries (20).

```
var retryCounter = 0;
function checkIfAnalyticsLoaded() {
  if ((typeof ga === 'function' && ga.loaded) || retryCounter++ > 20) {
    // ga() puts your method in the Command Queue, 
    // which is applied after GA is done with initialization
    ga(yourFunctionHere()); 
  } else {
    // Retry. 
    setTimeout(checkIfAnalyticsLoaded, 500);
  }
}

// Auto load
(function () {
  checkIfAnalyticsLoaded();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this, but I built a helper function out of it that lets me pass in a function and arguments, and they're called when Google Analytics is loaded.  It checks once every half second, and stops checking after a minute if Google Analytics hasn't loaded.  I thought this might be helpful for others.

Usage:

```
function add(a,b){alert(a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + (a+b));}
_mygaq(add,1,2);
```

Code:

```
function _mygaq(fn) {
  this._count = this._count || 0;
  this._running = this._running || false;
  this._q = this._q || [];
  if(arguments.length>0){
    this._q.push({"f":fn,"p":Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)});
  } else {
    this._count++;
  }
  if ((window._gat && window._gat._getTracker) || window.urchinTracker) {
    this._count = 0;
    this._running = false;
    while (this._q.length > 0){
      var _innr = this._q[0];
      this._q = this._q.slice(1);
      _innr.f.apply(_innr.f, _innr.p);
    }
  } else {
    if( (arguments.length==0) || (!this._running && arguments.length>0)){
      if(this._count < 120) setTimeout('_mygaq()', 500);
      this._running = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the most elegant solution to be something like this:

```
const isAnalyticsLoaded = Promise.race([
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 10000)),
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const isLoaded = () => window.ga && window.ga.loaded
      ? resolve()
      : setTimeout(isLoaded, 200)

    isLoaded()
  })
])
```

The first promise is only for timeout in case ga never gets loaded. You can of course `reject` instead of `resolve` if that's what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I have a different solution for this if anyone cares to try it out. This assumes your Google Analytics Object is 'ga'. Change your timeout and max tries to suit your application.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    function checkIfAnalyticsLoaded() {
        if (window.ga) {
            //LOADED!
        } else {
            counter = counter + 1;
            if (counter < 6){
                setTimeout('checkIfAnalyticsLoaded()', 200);
            } else {
                //LOADED!
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = checkIfAnalyticsLoaded();
    </script>
```

Comment: The inline GA script itself defines window.ga immediately. So, it's always defined.

Comment: @EricMuyser Yes that's true for inline GA scripts, but not for GA when implemented via Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score -4):

you may also look into the [new Asynchronous Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html) and then you wont need to check you can just do whatever and it will send the data as soon as it loads...