# detect and load google analytics if not already loaded, skip if its already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have a javascript widget that contains a google analytics loading code. There is already google analytics loading code on the html page where the javascript is going to live. The ga.js files are loading twice and the bounce rate has gone to less than 1% due to the multiple loading of ga.js.

Is there a javascript solution where I could check if the page already has ga.js loaded then skip the loading within the javascript widget file and load ga.js if it is already not loaded?

This is the code i'm using but it seems to load the ga.js again even if the page already has ga.js.

Note: The javascript widget that contains the below code is loaded within a document.ready call and the google analytics loading code is present within the head tag of the html page.

```
function loadtracking() {
    window._gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXX']);
    window._gaq.push(['_setDomainName', window.location.hostname]);
    window._gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
}

if(window._gat && window._gat._getTracker && typeof _gat != 'undefined'){//if site already has google analytics loaded
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    window._gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-43609253-2']);
    window._gaq.push(['_setDomainName', window.location.hostname]);
}else{ //if site DOES NOT have google analytics loaded
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    loadtracking(); 
}
```

Comment: This question have been already asked and answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954910/javascript-detect-if-google-analytics-is-loaded-yet

Comment: @Akaryatrh that answer is from 2009... lots of thing changed since then