# Display unknown hidden field values on page

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-analytics

I'm currently using a script to get data about the visitor from Google Analytics and pass it to hidden input fields on a form. I'm using the script from this article: http://bit.ly/1PiPxrp

If you look at a working example here (http://codepen.io/saltmktg/pen/meERex - the function starts on line 91), you can click the "Show GA Info" button and see the alerts for each piece of data. (You won't see real info because the Analytics script is linked to a different account, i.e not JSFiddle.) Nevertheless, **my problem is that I want to display this data on the actual page - without a visitor having to click the "Show GA Info" button.** I want them to see the data right when they hit the page.

Right now the `populateHiddenFields` function only populates the hidden fields when you click the "Show GA Info" button. I tried things like `<body onload="populateHiddenFields(this);` and `window.onload = populateHiddenFields` - but I can't get the function to work elsewhere on the page (apart from being tied to the actual form).

Please let me know if I can provide any more info or examples. Once again, I'd simply like to visibly display the visitor's Google Analytics tracking info on the page. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly, so I imagine that you don't pass the form in the argument. You can make in onload or in a DOM ready event (as you want):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojLwNW

```
 <body onload="populateHiddenFields(document.forms[0])">
```

I make `document.forms[0]` because is the only form in page. You can pass the object by ID or by the form name.

Good luck

Comment: Okay thanks so much, this really helps! I added `<div id="demo"></div>` to the page, where one of the Google Analytics values now populates.

Comment: One final question: I'd like to append the dynamically generated Google Analytics value (in this case "f.source.value" - from line 93) to the end of an iframe src on the page (the iframe src starts on line 138). Ideally it would appear as a parameter. For example: `http://fakesite.com/test?=analyticsSource`

I've tried a number of solutions, but can't seem to place the value at the end of the iframe src. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Here's the updated example: http://codepen.io/saltmktg/pen/meERex

Many thanks once again for all your help!

Comment: If you want to update the url of the iframe: `document.getElementById("testIframe").src = document.getElementById("testIframe").src + "&"+ f.source.value;` that adds the source to the end of the URL

Comment: Thanks so much Marcos - you've been a tremendous help! I really appreciate the smart, simple solutions and fast responses. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :) Upvote this answer please. See you soon!

Comment: I would, but unfortunately I don't have enough credit earned yet.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the updates to your code to make it work:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvjWYz

All the values appear in your alerts.

If you'd like to show them on screen, make your hidden inputs type='text' instead.

The fundamental problem with the original code is that populateHiddenFields expects a parameter to reference the form, and calling it onload doesn't pass that reference.

Thanks to [javascript - Detect if Google Analytics is loaded yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954910/javascript-detect-if-google-analytics-is-loaded-yet) for some code I referenced to make sure Google Analytics was done loading first.

My additions:

```
function checkIfAnalyticsLoaded(f) {
  //See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1954977/1913396
  if (window._gat && window._gat._getTracker) {
    populateHiddenFields(f);
  } else if (window.urchinTracker) {
    populateHiddenFields(f);
  } else {
    // Retry. Probably want to cap the total number of times you call this.
    setTimeout(500, checkIfAnalyticsLoaded());
  }
}

function startOnce() {

  //See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1954977/1913396
  if(window._gaq) 
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  //end

  frm = frm || document.getElementById("contactform");
  //or
  //frm = frm || document.getElementsByName('contactform')[0];

  checkIfAnalyticsLoaded(frm);                           
}

var frm = null;
```

I added an id attribute to your form.

Then, at the bottom of the body:

```
  //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startOnce, false);
  (function(){ setTimeout(startOnce, 50); })();
```

Use either.

Comment: Thanks FesterCluck, I appreciate it!